# Flink Modify KeySelector based ProcessWindow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have the following flow

```
datastream.keyBy(K).timeWindow(...).process(A).timeWindowAll(...).process(B)
```

I do some calculations in `processAllWindowFunction` B, based on which I want to modify `KeySelector` behavior in K.

My initial thoughts are to use `QueryableState` in B which I query and update K accordingly. Any thoughts? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" solution is to have B write the pertinent info to some sort of message queue, and to add that message queue as another source.